# Gitlab CI build pending issue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I don't know where from that problem comes. I sure, I didn't do anything like that, I'm just have worked in a usual mode. Can some one help me to fix that?

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I can't merge any commit project

Comment: That says CI build pending for over 2 last days

Comment: Have you checked what the build is currently doing? See if it hangs somewhere.